# Set focus on appear

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a page that has a lot of JS created elements. So i wish to focus a textarea after it appear. I try to make it with help of `addEventListener` like so:

```
mytextarea.addEventListener('someEvent', function(e)
    {
    this.focus();
    });
```

My problem is, that i can not found the right Event, that would be fired at the moment, when textarea get appended in the document, like here

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(mytextarea);
```

Native JS Only please. Thank you

Comment: Can't you say `mytextarea.focus()` right after you append it? Or write your own append function that includes a call to `.focus()`.

Comment: It is not so simply, because it is how a Lego constructor. And at the append moment, i don't have info what would be appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(mytextarea);
mytextarea.focus();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QNpjH/)

Comment: It is not so simply, because it is how a Lego constructor. And at the append moment, i don't have info what would be appended.

Comment: @BASILIO how can you not now what you append when you append it?

Comment: 3-4 Constructor, that called one out of other in for and while loops and pushing one array of data forward, at te end it looks so out document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(constructor(data_array));

Answer (score 0):

Put your `focus` in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Here
});
```

This mean your `textarea` is appended to the `document`.

And without jQuery :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
//here
});
```

Comment: How to write it without JQuery?

Comment: window.addEventListener('load', function () {       });

Comment: Is it not means, that it would be fired after a window is complete loaded? Because this textarea going to be displayed not at the begin, also after some action of user.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_autofocus.asp) should work:

```
<textarea autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: And how to get it with JS? I create this element with JS, do you mean el.autofocus = true; would be working?

Comment: @BASILIO yes this is how you would access the property. But it doesn't make sense to set it with javascript, as js is loaded later than html. This will work if you put it in html but most likely will not work if you set it later with javascript. If you want to focus textarea with javascript just use .focus() method.

Comment: I have tried "textarea.autofocus = true;" in console it give me a TRUE back, but has no effect, in my constructor, it give no error or notice out, but still don't work. I would be like to use a simply .focus() but i need the right event, to hang it on the element, so that it would be fired in the right moment.